# How to format font for individual characters in cell beyond 255

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel VBA to build a cell with formatted markup text. It works fine until the cell exceeds 255 characters. At that point Font properties are not being set correctly.

I use VBA to add characters with `Range.Value = Range.Value & newchar`, and that works fine. But using `Range.Characters(n,1).Font.property` (e.g. `Name`, `Color`, `Strikethrough`, `Underline`) to set Font properties of individual characters does not work properly once the cell exceeds 255 characters. How can I apply Font properties to individual characters when a cells has more than 255 characters?

Sorry-- that was not a very good description of the problem. I was adding a character and immediately formatting font of that character, then add and format the next character, and so on. To go beyond 255 characters, I need to use &, but that clobbers the font formatting on text already in the cell.

Comment: Specifically, when I use Characters().Text to add characters, it refuses to add any more characters once it hits 255,. I can use & to add characters beyond 255, but this clobbers the font formatting on characters previously added to the cell. Fortunately, Characters.Font works beyond 255 (as posts show), I might  have to do it in two steps -- first add all the characters using &, and then apply font formatting. Ugh. Any alternatives?.

Answer (score 0):

how are you ?

So i tried your code , and did this to fill the Cell A1 with 255 "A"'s and 255 "B"'s

[image: here is the code]

And then used Character Function

there is the result

[image]

Maybe you are using the wrong way the function `Characters(1,256)`

Characters first parameter is Init char , and second parameter is How much characters after the first one.

Hope it help you

Comment: Starting with the cell contents of 510 formatted characters as generated by your code, how can I add a 511th character without perturbing the font formatting of the existing 510? cells(1,1).Characters(511,1).Text = "x" fails to add the character; cells(1,1).Value = cells(1,1).Value & "x" adds the new character but seems to clobber the formatting of existing text,

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what you are doing wrong without seeing more of your code.  But here is one way to format individual characters in a cell. And I've tested it with 30,000 characters in the cell (although that takes a long time).  The code below will create a cell with     characters and format certain characters with multiple characteristics.  The example is 750 characters.

```
Option Explicit
Sub par()
    Dim R As Range
    Dim S As String
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

Set R = Range("A1")

For J = 1 To 10
For I = 48 To 65 + 26 * 2 + 5
    S = S & Chr(I)
Next I
Next J

Debug.Print Len(S)
R = S

For I = 1 To Len(S)
    Select Case Mid(S, I, 1)
        Case "A", "D", "Y", "a", "t", "x", "8"
        With R.Characters(I, 1)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Color = vbRed
            .Font.Strikethrough = True
            .Font.Size = .Font.Size + 2
        End With
    End Select
Next I

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Starting with the cell contents of 750 formatted characters as generated by your code, how can I add a 751th character without perturbing the font formatting of the existing 750? R.Characters(751,1).Text = "x" fails to add the character; R.Value = R.Value & "x" adds the new character but seems to clobber the formatting of existing text.

Comment: @tbg22 I think the fact that your code seems to work with less than 255 characters is an anomaly. Since the Characters object is not a collection, MS must be using some other technique that allows you to extend it under certain circumstances.

Comment: Ron, thanks for the responses. Are you aware of any method to extend the cell contents that would preserve the font formatting of existing text? Is my only recourse to make a first pass through the data to add characters, followed by a second pass that applies font formatting?

Comment: @tbg22 I don't know of any other way to do that in Excel. Having said that, it seems there should be a way, since it can be done manually, but the mechanics of doing that are hidden, even with a macro recording.